# Create multiindex Dataframe with column containing a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm having a pandas dataframe that looks like this
in E I have a list

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | [obj1, obj2,obj3] |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | empty list |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | [obj1] |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | [obj1, obj2] |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | empty list |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | [obj1, obj2,obj3] |

I want to make it a multiindex (or any kind of dataframe) that looks like this.
That I have a row for each value of the list, but without duplicting the values

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | obj1 |
|  |  |  |  | obj2 |
|  |  |  |  | obj3 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | obj1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | obj1 |
|  |  |  |  | obj2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | obj1 |
|  |  |  |  | obj2 |
|  |  |  |  | obj3 |

But I cannot figure out how to do it.

I tried using

```
dfexplode(['E'],ignore_index=True)
```

but this enflattens the list but duplicated the column values A-D. So when I count the values, I also count the duplicates.

Any ideas?

Comment: `So when I count the values, I also count the duplicates.` What do you mean? Can't you groupby and count? Or just use the original counts from the original data frame?

Comment: `df.set_index(['A','B','C','D']).explode('E')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode your data and reset the index to compare it with the shifted one. This mask allows you to overwrite all values for a-d where the index equals the shifted index. The following code does this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_exploded = df.explode(column="e").reset_index()
df_exploded.loc[df_exploded["index"] == df_exploded["index"].shift(), df.columns[:-1]] = ""
df_exploded = df_exploded.drop(columns="index")
```

It results in the following table:

```py
    a  b  c  d    e
0   1  1  1  1   10
1                11
2                12
3   1  1  2  1  NaN
4   1  1  2  1    3
5   1  2  2  1   40
6                20
7   2  1  1  1  NaN
8   2  1  2  1   30
9                12
10               11
```

Note, if you want numeric columns, you can also assign `nan` values instead of empty strings. To do so, just adjust the following line:

```py
df_exploded.loc[df_exploded["index"] == df_exploded["index"].shift(), df.columns[:-1]] = pd.NA # or np.nan if you want to use numpy
```